# Painting cabinet doors

Tags: paint, cabinetry, door

I'm going to paint my MDF kitchen cabinet doors and want a professional finish.

I'm testing on some MDF offcuts to perfect the finish. I have used a paint sprayer using Dulux satinwood, finish does look fairly even however you can still feel a roughness and little bumps in it when you feel it.

I have created a dust free spray booth using plastic sheeting. How can I improve this further? I have got a better result using a spray can but that's a very expensive option for a whole kitchen.

Is Dulux paint suitable for a sprayer?

Are there paints that are better for cabinet doors?

Comment: What kind of sprayer are you using?  Airless or HVLP?  The paint you're using appears to be water-based, but is it a water-borne alkyd type or a normal latex?  For durability and transferring details I'd suggest not using a latex paint.  Either way, a water-based product will cause issues with raw MDF.  Either use an oil or shellac based primer first or plan on sanding back after your first coat.  The second coat should not cause as many issues as the MDF will now be "sealed".

Comment: @SaSSafraS1232 the sprayer is is a hvlp. I'm not sure on the paint type, not sure how to find out. All I know is it is dulux water based satinwood.  I have sealed the MDF with a shellac primer, sanded back and given 3 spray coats sanding between each layer.

Comment: Ok, that's very good information.  That definitely should have been included in the original question.

Comment: Some texture is almost guaranteed when spraying, even with very high-end paint and the most expensive spray equipment in the world slight texture is possible. There are ways to improve the inherent texture from the paint/process (diluting the paint slightly and getting your spray distance *just right* are two important ones that work together) but the honest truth is you can't expect to get a factory-perfect finish (esp with a waterbased consumer-level paint) no matter how good your sprayer is and how well you nail your technique. So what I'm saying is you might have to settle for good enough.

Comment: @Graphus thanks for the response, I have been diluting the paint down more and more. An issue I have found is the paint isn't a fine mist when it hits the wood, instead it forms lots of bigger droplets. I keep spraying back and forward until most of this fills in and the surface is quite wet. It all seems to self level not so bad then. I'm not sure why I don't get a fine mist laying on the MDF. I have a 2.5mm tip I believe. Paint is thinned now much further than required by the instructions to improve this more. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Another point is that making the material thinner isn't exactly the same as improving how it flows out.  You might also try adding a flow-promoting additive like floetrol.  Some people also recommend a drop of dish soap, but personally I'd be worried that this could cause other problems with the material...

Comment: 2.5mm is a really big tip.  Most systems top out at 2.0mm.  What system exactly are you using?  What other tips are available?

Comment: @SaSSafraS1232 I didn't want to spend much money for first time using a sprayer. Its a erbauer erb561srg hvlp with a 2.5mm nozzle. There don't seem to be any other nozzles for it

Comment: Ahh, you might need to step up to a compressor-based system or a higher-quality turbine with finer tips.  Those cheaper turbine systems are mostly designed as price-conscious alternatives to airless.  The go-to "cheap" turbine system is the Earlex 5500.  If you can get a decently sized compressor there are tons of cheap guns that will work great.

Comment: I know exactly what you mean by the bigger droplets and pretty sure that's going to be a big part of what's giving you texture problems. Good atomisation is always considered key to smoothness, in all spraying. And another issue is you can't continue to thin using just water without issues. The makers are probably overly conservative about dilution but with paint like you're using I *think* you can only thin by poss 25% max without compromising the strength of the dry paint. This is a guess, based on the much lower percentage that the makers tell us *is* safe — often single digits, maybe 10%.

Comment: @SaSSafraS1232 I can find a cheap gravity fed 0.8mm hvlp spray gun. Can you just attach these to a compressor? Do you need a special compressor?

Comment: .8mm is actually way on the other side of the spectrum - too small for anything but the thinnest material, like dyes in alcohol.  Look for something in the 1.4mm or 1.6mm range for a good general use with most woodworking film finishes or oil-based paints.

Comment: @SaSSafraS1232 cool thanks, seen a 1.2mm too. Will a hvlp spray gun work with any compressor? Is there anything I need to look out for. Not sure what makes a hvlp and hvlp is it the gun or the air supply.

Comment: You don't need a special compressor per se.  However, you do need one with a decently large throughput.  Look for something in the 1.5hp or 4SCFM@90psi range, otherwise you'll end up having to stop for the compressor to rebuild pressure.  The air demands will vary wildly from gun to gun, though...

Comment: @SaSSafraS1232 I can see a reasonably priced one with this spec 2hp Motor

222Ltr/min Free Air Delivery

Max. Pressure: 10bar

Oil-Free Lubrication

1 Air Coupling

2 Tank Pressure Gauges

All the spray gun says is required 1.5 - 2 bar

Comment: That sounds like a pretty beefy compressor, it should be plenty big enough to paint with.  You'll also want to get a mini regulator and mount it directly to the gun.  The one at the compressor won't be accurate due to the "drag" of the air in the hose.  Make sure you do all readings on the regulator while the air is flowing (i.e. half trigger-pull.)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the "bumps/roughness" you're seeing are "orange peel".

It could also be a "sandpaper" texture.  That's usually an indication of a "dry" spray.  I.e. the material is drying before it hits the surface.  It could also be dust nibs which are contamination in either the air (which I doubt because you said you set up a makeshift booth) or in your material (make sure you're straining it.)

Orange peel is caused by the material not atomizing sufficiently.  Basically you're getting "clumps" of material hitting the surface that don't "flow out" into a smooth, even liquid film.

Make sure your material is thin enough. Get a viscosity cup to measure it and thin it down until it matches the recommendation from your gun's manufacturer.  This is the #1 cause of orange peel.  Most paint is designed for brushing or airless and is too thick for HVLP.  Latex paint in particular is way too thick to use with HVLP.

Make sure the material is well mixed, that your tip set is big enough, that your air is all the way up (at least to start), that you're setting your regulator while the air is flowing, and that you're not too far away.  Also make sure that the bleed hole in your cup isn't blocked with old material.